# How to assign local storage value to html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am passing the info from one page to other page using local storage, now I have to assign this info to html element, How I will do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script>

  $( document ).ready(function() {
        var globalarray = [];
        var arrLinks =[];
        arrLinks = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("globalarray"));
    $(#booking)// How to assign arrLinks here

  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>

<p id="booking">Not loaded yet.</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How about `$('#booking').html(arrLinks)` ?

Comment: $(#booking) should be $('#booking'). And please show us the contents of your array.

Comment: `$('#booking').text(arrLinks)`?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the html function of jquery

```
$('#booking').html(arrLinks);
```

As well as you need to pass it as a JSON string rather than a JSON.

So do not parse the JSON.

```
arrLinks = window.localStorage.getItem("globalarray");
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qyeun5g2/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$(#booking).html(arrLinks);
```

I suppose that `arrLinks` is an array of `anchors` stored in the local storage. Getting them from the storage an passing them to the `html` if the paragraph with `id` booking, they will be appeared there.

```js
$(function(){
var arrLinks = ["<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'>StackOverflow</a>", 
                "<a href='http://www.twitter.com'>Twitter</a>"];
$("#booking").html(arrLinks);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="booking"></p>
```